# Is mod prime good enough as a hash function for a hashtable in C

Tags: c, hashtable, hash-function

I need a hash function that is as efficient as possible, for a hash table (actually a hash set) that uses probing (open addressing) for collision resolution. The entries stored in the table are all 4 byte ints that take on random values over the range.

I am considering something even faster than djb2, something like

```
value mod LARGE_PRIME
```

Then mod it again with my bucket size. I suppose this prime is necessarily bigger than my bucket size, which means I also have some kind of sanity limit on how big my table has to grow (it probably won't ever get past 256 entries).

I don't require any cryptography aspects of hash function - as long as it isn't terribly collision-prone, it should work fine.

Will this make a good hash function? Can I define a specific algorithm for my hash table capacity every time I resize to improve it?

Comment: What do you mean by `LARGE_PRIME`? `value mod LARGE_PRIME` is `value` for all values smaller than `LARGE_PRIME`.

Comment: Good question. I estimate my table to be no bigger than 256 entries, so some prime around 1000, I suppose. Question edited.

Comment: "take on random values" - that "random" means you don't need hashing or primes, and your "as efficient as possible" might or might not be stringent enough for you to care, but a simple bitwise-AND can mask a larger random value into a power-of-2 bucket count more efficiently than a mod operation (when the bucket count isn't known until runtime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right hash function boils down to the data you are hashing: how random are your values? If your values are uniformly distributed over the range, and the range is much larger than the number of hash buckets, then just using

```
value MOD number_of_buckets
```

will be a reasonable hash function - adding in `MOD <prime>` won't actually give you very much, and in fact might well make the hashing worse (because some buckets will be under- or over-used more than they would otherwise have been).

Primes aren't magic - they can sometimes be used to "smooth out" correlation effects due to common factors, but if you don't have those correlations to begin with, you may be better off without them - especially if speed is paramount!

Comment: Hmm good point! I guess I was a little concerned about how using 2^n number of buckets might make it more collision-prone. I see that it doesn't really matter now, if my input is truly random!